# Creating spatial queries in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatial-query

How can I create spatial queries in QGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database -> DBManager or Layer -> Postgis Layer , select table and "set filter" , but you can define only WHERE clause. All tested data needs to be in database and you need to use postgis functions.  If you want to compare data in QGIS and Postgis load for an example shp file into QGIS , load postgis layer and use Vector tools (for vector data)

Example for postgis layer :

```
ST_IsValid(geom) IS TRUE
```

Example for DBManger SQL

```
SELECT * FROM xxx as x , yyyy as y WHERE ST_Intersects(x.geom , y.geom) IS TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the core **Spatial Query Plugin**.

[image]

You will find it in Vector > Spatial Query > Spatial Query

[image]